# Scala/Lift Database Connections

Tags: database, scala, lift

I am working on a new web application using Scala with Lift. I want to make it reusable so others might install it on their own servers for their own needs. I come out of a PHP background where it is common practice to create an install form asking for database connection details. This information is stored in a configuration file and used by the rest of the PHP application for connecting to the database. It is extremely convenient for the user because everything is contained within the directory storing the PHP files. They are free to define everything else. My Java/Scala background has all been enterprise work where an application was only intended to run on the database we setup for it. It was not meant to be installed on others' web servers or with different databases.

So my question is how is this typically done for the Java/Scala world? If there are open source applications implementing the mainstream solution, feel free to point me to those too.

Answer (score 2):

I use this to set up the database:

```
val vendor =
  new StandardDBVendor(
    Props.get("db.driver") openOr "org.h2.Driver",
    Props.get("db.url") openOr "jdbc:h2:mem:db;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE",
    Props.get("db.user"), 
    Props.get("db.password"))
LiftRules.unloadHooks.append(vendor.closeAllConnections_! _)
DB.defineConnectionManager(DefaultConnectionIdentifier, vendor)
```

The 'Props' referred to will then be (by default) in the file default.props in the props directory in resources.

**Updated**: This is what I do on servers in production. With 'Props.whereToLook' you provide a function that retrieves an input stream of the configuration. This can be a file as in the example below or you could for example fetch it over network socket.

You will probably let the application to fail with an error dialog.

```
val localFile = () => {
  val file = new File("/opt/jb/myapp/etc/myapp.props")
  if (file.exists) Full(new FileInputStream(file)) else Empty
}
Props.whereToLook = () => (("local", localFile) :: Nil)
```

Comment: How does a random user use their own properties file then? Do they have to open the WAR and insert their own?

Comment: Where is the standard location for a file like this to exist? It would be nice to allow users to have it wherever they want so as not to interfere with anything else they want to do with their own server. This means I would have to put it as a relative path, perhaps in an app server's workdir? If in the workdir, then where? Do I force them to have a folder with my app's name? Then it's not fully customizable in that they cannot have another application already using that workdir dir name on the same server. Am I asking too much?

Comment: In the updated version I have used the option to override standard location of files (which is inside the produced (jw)ar-artifact). The file is now specified to be read from /opt/jb/myapp/etc/myapp.props. Here you can specify whatever file location you want, you could for example use home directory (System.getProperty("user.home")).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am missing your points.
By default, Lift use Scala source file(`Boot.scala`) to configure all the settings, because Lift doesn't wanna introduce other language into the framework, however you can override some of the configurations using a .properties file.

In Java/Scala world, we use .properties file. It's just a plain text file used for configuration or localization etc,just like text configuration files in PHP.

Lift Framework has it's default support for the external database configuration files, you check out the code in `Boot.scala`, that's if a .properties file existed, the database will initialized using the connection configuration, if it doesn't, it will use the source file configuration.